# Finding precise solution for x in complicated single-variable equation...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need an exact answer for $x$ in the following algebraic expression: 
$$
x^{4/3} - 2\sqrt{2}x^2 + 2\sqrt{2} = 0
$$
I don't need or want an approximate answer, I already know that $x≈1.20569$. So any exponential expressions (no matter the integer in the exponent is), cannot be evaluated; I need it (or them) to be left as an exponential expression(s). Any websites that I have used (including new websites that I've searched for) are not helpful, and do not give me an answer in the form that I need. (This is despite these websites working perfectly fine for less complicated equations). If you do manage to help me with finding $x$ in its exact form, then thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try substituting $u=x^{2/3}$ to obtain:
$$u^2-2\sqrt{2}u^3+2\sqrt{2}=0$$
Then, one may use the [cubic formula](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or alternatively we have $$x^{4/3}=2\sqrt{2}(x^2-1)$$ and after cube the equation
we get $$x^4=(2\sqrt{2})^3(x^2-1)^3$$
this yields to
$${x}^{4}-16\,\sqrt {2}{x}^{6}+48\,\sqrt {2}{x}^{4}-48\,\sqrt {2}{x}^{2}
+16\,\sqrt {2}
=0$$
which can factorize into $$1/2\,\sqrt {2} \left( -32\,{x}^{6}+\sqrt {2}{x}^{4}+96\,{x}^{4}-96\,{x
}^{2}+32 \right)
=0$$
note that $$x=1/24\,{\frac {\sqrt {6}\sqrt {\sqrt [3]{13826\,\sqrt {2}+576+768\,
\sqrt {648+3\,\sqrt {2}}} \left(  \left( 13826\,\sqrt {2}+576+768\,
\sqrt {648+3\,\sqrt {2}} \right) ^{2/3}+\sqrt {2}\sqrt [3]{13826\,
\sqrt {2}+576+768\,\sqrt {648+3\,\sqrt {2}}}+96\,\sqrt [3]{13826\,
\sqrt {2}+576+768\,\sqrt {648+3\,\sqrt {2}}}+192\,\sqrt {2}+2 \right) 
}}{\sqrt [3]{13826\,\sqrt {2}+576+768\,\sqrt {648+3\,\sqrt {2}}}}}
$$ is one solution of this equation, all Solutions can be expressed by radicals